# How to build the driver for cx2072x codec

Tags: kernel, atom

I would like to use Ubuntu on a computer that has an Atom z8300 processor. Everything works quite well, except the sound which requires cx2072x driver.

I would like to build the driver for this codec.

As I understand it is provided here:
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/tiwai/sound.git/?h=topic/asus-e100h-4.13

I would like to know how to merge the driver into the kernel tree and configure the build process so that the codec is built.

Could you help?

Comment: Please use a Live USB of one of the current versions of Lubuntu and test that sound works. There was a bug in older versions. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1563110

Comment: I am currently on Ubuntu 17.10. The sound is not working neither with stock nor with the 4.15 kernel from the Kernel PPA. What works indeed is the solution proposed by Andrei Aldea in this comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1563110/comments/116 The problem is that Andrei gives us only a binary version of the kernel. On the github page: https://github.com/Grippentech/Asus-E200HA-Linux-Post-Install-Script he has placed a note about the fact that he has no longer the time to work on  his kernel version. I would like to try to build the kernel myself from source.

Answer (score 0):

I recently needed the cx2027x codec aswell (for an asus e200ha). You are correct, the repository you linked does have the fixes, but for an older kernel.

The last two nights i sat down to merge and update these older fixes into a newer kernel, and i got it to work with 4.16.

Here is a fork with these updated fixes. You can find .deb packages of the amd64-variant of the kernel in "releases": https://github.com/heikomat/linux

Along with the kernel you need two ucm-files for alsa, and copy them to `/usr/share/alsa/ucm/chtcx2072x`. You probably also need to disable `realtime-scheduling` in `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`. For a more detailed description on what to do, see [this little manual](https://github.com/heikomat/linux/tree/cx2072x/cx2072x_fixes_and_manual) (it's in the same fork)

Comment: Wow, this is really good news! I am currently running the mentioned 4.13 version by Takashi Iwai, which works quite well (except for HDMI video performance, some occasional video quirks and IIO accelerometer not working properly with iio-sensor-proxy) but I am willing to try your merged version. I will try to do it in next few days and get back to you. Cheers!

Comment: @kmbt sounds good :) i'm in the process of buying a cx2072x device so i can further test and develop on this and maybe get more fixes merged and things working.